# Using onclick in AMP

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I have the following which works in HTML:

```
<a onclick="__tcfapi('displayConsentUi',2, function() {});">Manage Privacy Settings</a>
```

However, this doesn't work in AMP since scripts aren't allowed, which I understand.

I have tried using the following but it's not working either:

```
<amp-script layout="container" script="manage" class="amp-my-custom-script-menu">
    <li><button on="tap:manage">Manage Privacy Settings</button></li>
</amp-script>

<script id="manage" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
    __tcfapi('displayConsentUi',2, function() {});
</script>
```

It's not working and I'm getting an error in the console:

```
[Action] Target "manage" not found for action [tap:manage]
```

Comment: I'd try "2 - Inline Script" https://ampforwp.com/tutorials/article/how-to-add-custom-scripts-in-amp/.  It adds the event handler via the script

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that but getting an error  - error-reporting.js:198 [ amp-script ] amp-script[script="inline_amp"].js could not find element with # inline_amp .​​​